# Material design navigation drawer item selected styling

Tags: android, material-design

Afternoon,

I've attempted to find the answer for this but there doesn't seem to be any direct explanation for something that I hope should be quite simple!

I've just started using the material design navigation drawer and need to change the background colour of the selected item in the drawer.

This is the code for the items within the drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/item1"
        android:title="Item 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/item2"
        android:title="Item 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/item3"
        android:title="Item 3" />
</group>
```

I have the following in my MainActivity xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="#202020"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

I've managed the style the drawer with background and text colour but as mentioned above, I now need to change the background colour of the item selected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new style to the *styles.xml*:

*res / values / styles.xml*

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#selectedItemColor</item>
</style>
```

Set the new style to the `NavigationView`:

*res / layout / activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" 
    app:theme="@style/TextAppearance" />
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! I spent a good hour or so trying to find this in the docs, so thankyou, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set  `**android:checked="false"**` in drawer item for unchecked item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/item1"
        android:title="Item 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/item2"
        android:title="Item 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/item3"
        android:title="Item 3" />
</group>
```

then you have to do from programming using following code to change selected item background colour

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.isChecked())
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: I have the correct item being selected but I can't find a way to change the selected item background colour. At the moment it's black and I need to change it to blue. Not sure this is the answer?

Comment: its working for me. On setChecked(true) it set the selected background item colour based on app using theme so try to change the theme colours

Comment: That's what I am trying to work out, which bit of the theme do I need to specify the colour of this? Primary colour isn't working?

Comment: in that case you have to set custom theme of your navigation drawer like  <style name="NavigationStyle">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#2AFF2A</item>
    </style>
and after that just simply set theme in navigation drawer
app:theme="@style/NavigationStyle"